# AES-256-GCM Encryption from Ruby & Decryption with Golang

Tags: ruby, go, encryption, aes-gcm

I have an encryption in Ruby with `aes-256-gcm`

```
require 'openssl'
key = "972ec8dd995743d981417981ac2f30db"
iv = "6a825c25ea74"
auth_data = "73f6828fc5be"
plaintext = "John Doe play foo bar"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.iv = iv
cipher.key = key
cipher.auth_data = auth_data
cipherText = cipher.update(plaintext) + cipher.final
authTag = cipher.auth_tag
hexString = (cipherText + iv + authTag).unpack('H*').first
```

the hextString result looks like

```
fa03a24cad007ceaadc34c22edff943cb58fe514ed36613832356332356561373425f6bc5724b956daae151c8d78a21263
```

I want to decrypt it in Go

```
key := "972ec8dd995743d981417981ac2f30db"
iv := "6a825c25ea74"
authData := "73f6828fc5be"
hexString, _ := hex.DecodeString("fa03a24cad007ceaadc34c22edff943cb58fe514ed36613832356332356561373425f6bc5724b956daae151c8d78a21263")

block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

plaintext, err := aesgcm.Open(nil, []byte(iv), hexString, []byte(authData))
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

I got `cipher: message authentication failed`.
and Also I don't get the point about authData in golang, I can't fine it in here https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#NewGCM

Comment: The `authData` is actually `Associated Data`(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Authenticated_encryption_with_associated_data_(AEAD)), described in the [`cipher.AEAD` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#AEAD)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nonce (iv) does not belong in the middle of the ciphertext. The hex-encoded output you want here from the ruby example is only the `cipherText` + `authTag`. Since the nonce must be sent along with the ciphertext, it is common to prefix the ciphertext with the nonce if you so choose, but you must trim that off before deciphering the message. (Also note that your `key`, `iv` and `auth_data` values appear to be hex strings, but they are being used as raw bytes which may be adding to some of the confusion).

Re-arranging the bytes of the message to prepend the nonce, gives us this example: https://play.golang.org/p/YV5FugSyM5_G

```
key := []byte("972ec8dd995743d981417981ac2f30db")
authData := []byte("73f6828fc5be")

msg, err := hex.DecodeString("366138323563323565613734fa03a24cad007ceaadc34c22edff943cb58fe514ed25f6bc5724b956daae151c8d78a21263")

block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

sz := aesgcm.NonceSize()
nonce, cipherText := msg[:sz], msg[sz:]

pt, err := aesgcm.Open(nil, nonce, cipherText, authData)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%q\n", pt)
```

> "John Doe play foo bar"

Comment: Brilliant, clearly explain.. I thank you JimB

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I originally used the [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) gem to encrypt the information.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
  // data: "7621276423"
  // encrypted_data: "Hz1HXFTfSyucPvy3iDoY1F4O5YmAx2skRa4="
  // encrypted_data_iv: "Ezk8f3+944gs4x5E"
  // license_key: "iUPGMBmppYA92kbciS5fIUe7gRcx6G025haOeAmEjU4="

  cipherText, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("Hz1HXFTfSyucPvy3iDoY1F4O5YmAx2skRa4=")
  nonce, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("Ezk8f3+944gs4x5E")
  key, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("iUPGMBmppYA92kbciS5fIUe7gRcx6G025haOeAmEjU4=")

    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    pt, err := aesgcm.Open(nil, nonce, cipherText, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%q\n", pt)
}

// "123456789"
```